# How can I force Word 2016 to read all text in Text to Speech?

Tags: microsoft-word

I need documents read, and can't install any software. Word stops reading after 4096 characters, very annoying. How can I make it just read everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reasonable solution: paste it to Outlook 2016, send the email to yourself, and press read all.

I perhaps should have said I need to do this in a work environment. Ergo, I can't go installing software or pasting sensitive info into random websites.

Why it's this way round I'm not sure. Word documents are usually longer than emails. But whatevs.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't increase the character limit on the Text to Speech in Microsoft Word. You will have to either (1) use another program or (2) be patient with Word.